# NetBeans 8.0.2 missing Java Desktop Application

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I recently installed latest version of NetBeans and when I tried to make a new project type "Java Desktop Application" it won't appear in Java category.
Please help?
I've installed this plugin:

- Java Swing Framework Library
- JDK Project for Netbeans

Even I installed all of java plugins. But no luck!

Comment: If your trying to create a Java project, try the JDK Project for Netbeans option

Comment: When I create a new project and choose category "Java" then it should show me an option to make "Java Desktop Application" but that's missing. I need to use that option active in my netbeans!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6p1y01
Look where "Java Application" there should an option of "Java Desktop Application' there.

Comment: The "Swing Application Framework" is no longer maintained and therefor the support for it in NetBeans has been removed about 4 years ago: http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=43775&highlight=204661

Comment: So, I need to install netbeans 7.0?

Comment: You can donload plugin. Solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263921/4097900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Java Desktop Application you may be referring the "Swing Application Framework" and that was [halted by Sun Microsystems before Java 7](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/09/java7_m5) around year 2009  end.

For developing Desktop Applications using Java in NetBeans you have multiple options as follows:

1. Using Matisse UI Builder
   The Matisse UI builder is available in NetBeans and you can create JFrame and JDialog classes in your application which can be used as your UI in any Java application.  This approach needs a lot of boilerplate code to be written for creating windows, menus and dialog boxes.  The next option is better if you want a professional cross platform Java Desktop Application
2. Using NetBeans Platform as base of your application
   NetBeans IDE is built on the top of NetBeans Platform and you can also use the NetBeans Platform to build your own Desktop application with many conventional features out of the box coming from the NetBeans Platform.  The NetBeans IDE comes with NetBeans Modules project types where you can choose the "NetBeans Platform Applciation: project type to create a desktop application.  There are lot of tutorials and help available for the NetBeans platform on NetBeans users list and platform mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for the answer, or if anyone out there who want help, then here is an option. I think you want the drag and drop option, right? Here you go.

Just Start `new project` as `Java` and `Java Application` as shown below:

[image: Selecting new project]

And then give any name to your project, like `helloworld` as shown below:

[image: setting project name]

After you click finish button, the `helloworld` package will be opened. Now go to the left (mostly) or right side of the screen there is a list of `projects`. Go to your project and right-click on `Source Packages` -> `New` -> `Other` as shown below:

[image: looking for the way]

Now another window opens, and select `Swing GUI Forms` from `Categories` and `JFrame Form` from `File Types`, then `Next` and give the `name` and `location` for the class.

[image: goigng through the way]

[image: finish]

Now the form should appear on the window. You can now go back to `source code` and go forth to `Design` as you want. Have a nice coding.